# can i connect two similar antennas to two ends of a cable to to re-transmit the signal received from one end?

Tags: signal, antenna, wifi, transmitter, receiver

Scenario:

I've set up two wifi hot spots outside of my house at distance lesser than 20 meters as i don't get any ISP signal inside my house. But the problem is now i get very weak signal in my house because of nature of walls. 
I'm afraid of buying any repeaters as they reduce the speed by two.

My Idea:

So i've thought of building two simple omni-directional WiFi antennas myself (such as biquad or helical) and connect them to each other by a cable, and put one at outdoor and other at indoor. But i'm not sure if this would work out, so i need your suggestions please..

Additional Infromation:
I got this idea  from following instructable, but it is not for WiFi, and not simple as i think
http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-2G3G4G-Wireless-Cell-Phone-Signal-Booster/

Comment: What has the setting-up of two wifi hot spots got to do with the problem? Are you saying that before you set them up your house ISP signal was OK?

Comment: @Andyaka, I'm not talking about ISP signal, but Wifi signal, that can i be able to pass the wall barrier with the technique in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a passive repeater such as you describe can work, however it does incur losses due to the cable, connectors and antenna efficiencies.  Whether these losses exceed the attenuation you would get with no repeater but a wall in the way is situation dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and i have another question, when repeaters reduce wifi speed to half the original speed of router, does that affect the speed of actual data transfer (say internet speed, which is far lower than original capacity of Router)